# SonarQube considering SQL DML entries to have duplicate values

Tags: sql, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have the below code in my Github respository:

```
INSERT INTO lookup_tables.view_da_status_lookup(status_id, object_type, status_name, status_type, ui_dropdown_flag, last_updt_ts)
    VALUES 
(1,'View','Validation success','Maker Validation',true,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(2,'View','Validation Failed','Maker Validation',true,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(3,'View','Approved','Checker Validation',true,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

`Maker Validation` is repeated in the DML and it expects us to use a variable and have the command in a PL-SQL construct.

This is the error I get:

```
Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal 1 times.
```

However, we do not have to implement PL-SQL. Is there a way to tell it to ignore the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[On the following link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/), you can find:

> **Exclude specific rules from specific files**
>
> **Analysis Scope > D. Issue > Exclusions > Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria**
>
> You can prevent specific rules from being applied to specific files by
> combining one or more pairs of strings consisting of a** rule key
> pattern and a **file path pattern.
>
> The key for this parameter is *sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria*.
> However, because it is a multi-value property, we recommend that only
> be set through the UI.

For example, if you use Maven, the setting should look like this:

```
<properties>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>e1,e2</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>squid:S00100</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>**/*Steps.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey>squid:S1118</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey>**/PropertyPlaceholderConfig.java</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey>
</properties>
```

where **e1** and **e2** are *local* rule names, **e1.ruleKey** is sonarqube rule id and **e1.resourceKey** is path to file.